# Vue search Ajax response array while typing

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, vue.js

I'm trying to filter a list when typing to text box which I get from Ajax call. The problem seems to be that the filter is applied before Ajax is ready.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="searchTerm">
<table>
    <tr v-for="food in filteredItems">
      <td>{{ food.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ food.energy }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

helpers/index.js:

```
export default {
  getFoods() {
  return Vue.http.get('http://localhost:3000/foods/allfoods')
         .then((response) => {
             return response.data;
    });
  }
}
```

Vue component:

```
import helpers from '../helpers'
export default {
  name: 'Search',
  mounted() {
    helpers.getFoods().then((response) => {
      this.foodData = response;
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchTerm: '',
      foodData: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.foodData.filter(function(food){return food.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase())>=0;});
    }
  }
```

When I load the page or start typing I get

> 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.searchTerm')'.

Everything works perfectly if I hard-code the foodData array.

Have I misunderstood something and/or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two questions: 1. Have you tried fixing the `this` references in `filteredItems`? 2. Where / how do you set `searchTerm`? I'm not seeing it in your template.

Comment: Added the missing <input> to HTML which I forgot to add here. Could you explain what you mean with fixing this references?

Comment: What Bert said ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your callback for the filter function in computed, `this` is not pointing to the Vue.

```
computed: {
  filteredItems() {
    return this.foodData.filter(function(food){
      // in this next line, this.searchTerm is likely undefined
      // because "this" is not the Vue
      return food.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });
  }
}
```

This is because you're using `function(food){...}` as your callback, and `this` will be the containing scope. Instead, use an arrow function, a closure, or `bind`.

```
computed: {
  filteredItems() {
    return this.foodData.filter(food => {
      // in this next line, this.searchTerm is likely undefined
      // because "this" is not the Vue
      return food.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });
  }
}
```

```js
console.clear()

const foods = [{
    name: "orange",
    energy: 10
  },
  {
    name: "apple",
    energy: 8
  },
  {
    name: "banana",
    energy: 12
  },
  {
    energy: 1000
  }
]

const Search = {
    name: 'Search',
    template: `
      <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="searchTerm">
        <table>
          <tr v-for="food in filteredItems">
            <td>{{ food.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ food.energy }}</td>
           </tr>
         </table>   
      </div>
    `,
    mounted() {
      setTimeout(() => this.foodData = foods, 500)
    },
    data() {
      return {
        searchTerm: '',
        foodData: [],
      }
    },
    computed: {
      filteredItems() {
        const searchTerm = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()
        return this.foodData
           .filter(food => food.name && food.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
      }
    }
  }
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  components: {Search}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <search></search>
</div>
```

See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately that did not solve it. By switching to arrow function I get 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'food.name.toLowerCase')'
Thanks for the link. That is definitely worth reading.

Comment: @ArtoSaarinen Do all your `food` objects have a `name`?

Comment: @ArtoSaarinen Added a working example (with a simulated API call). See if you can see where the difference is.

Comment: There actually might be one entry without name property. Database shows that there is 1345 entries and when doing find 'name' in atom it shows only 1344 occurrences. Got to look through all of them now.

Comment: @ArtoSaarinen a missing `name` would definitely cause an issue in the code as written because you can't call `toLowerCase` on undefined.

Comment: @ArtoSaarinen Added a filter that will handle null names.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it. One object is missing name. You saved my day!